# Why does DatagramPacket.getAddress() returns wrong remote address when remote client is on cellular network?

Tags: java, android, nat, cellular-network

I'm sending packets from an android client to my (AWS) server over a cellular network (e.g. AT&T). When the server receives the packet, the last octet given by DatagramPacket.getAddress() is wrong (i.e. it does not match Public IP Address lookups via the phone's browser). Can someone please explain why this would happen, and how I can correct for this?

For the record, this issue is not present when the android client is sending via my home network. I suspect it may have something to do with AT&T's NAT vs my home NAT but I just don't understand what is going on.

Code is very basic but provided just in case anyone asks:

```
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(8888);
serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
System.out.println(receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());
```

Comment: What do you mwan by looking up public ip adress via phone browser?

Comment: for example: if you type "ip" into google or use one of the many sites that will report your public IP.